# Automatic provisioning of VMs as self-hosted build agents

Tags: azure

In Azure Devops, my organization has an agent pool to manage build requests, where all agents are VMs.  However, because the workload is variable, for a substantial amount of time these VMs are idle.  We have a strong interest in changing things so that the VMs are dynamically created and added to the agent pool as requests come in, and then destroyed when not needed.  Is there a supported way in Azure Devops to do this?

We're familiar with Microsoft hosted agents, but believe that this won't work in our situation.  We're also investigating creating a more complicated custom solution using REST APIs that attempts to measure demand and provision/deallocate VMs appropriately, but if a simpler way exists this would be very helpful to us.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting example here of using Azure Functions and containers to configure serverless builds on demand - https://noelbundick.com/posts/serverless-vsts-build-agents-with-azure-container-instances/

You could probably adapt this to work with something like scale sets, if you had to use VMs for agents. Containers obviously will be faster to create.